# how to add a point using raw query?

Tags: postgresql, postgis, laravel-5

I need to insert a point into table of type postgres, I tried:

```
\DB::statement("SET search_path = postgis, public;");
\DB::statement("INSERT INTO points (latlong) VALUES( ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.060316 48.432044)', 4326));");
```

but I got error:

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function st_geomfromtext(unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO points (latlong) VALUES(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-...
^
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts. (SQL: INSERT INTO points (latlong) VALUES(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.060316 48.432044)', 4326));)
```

I am using postgres 9.4.5 with postgis installed .. any idea?

Comment: Your stored procedure doesn't exists, maybe it has a different name

Comment: I have no stored procedure, I just want to insert a point..

Comment: What is ST_GeomFromText('POINT(-71.060316 48.432044)', 4326));

Comment: Constructs a PostGIS ST_Geometry object from the OGC Well-Known text representation. its defined in the PostGIS, PostGIS is a spatial database extender for PostgreSQL object-relational database. It adds support for geographic objects allowing location queries to be run in SQL.

Comment: Well, I'm not familiar with it, but your DB doesn't recognize this object.

Comment: The type of `'POINT(-71.060316 48.432044)'` could not be determined. Try to typecast : `'POINT(-71.060316 48.432044)'::point` ( or ::geometry)

Comment: It seems that postgis is not installed. Have you tried to run it from psql? You may need to create the extension.

Comment: yes, postgis  was not installed, I've used a docker image for it, and now it fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Install PostGIS using something like `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis`
2. Creating a geometry by formatting a WKT string for `ST_GeomFromText` is not the best way to make a geometry (slower, lossy, error prone, etc.), *unless* your source data is already text. To make a point geometry from two floating point values, use something like:

   ```
   DB::insert('INSERT INTO points (latlong) VALUES(ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(?, ?), 4326))',
              [lng, lat]);
   ```

Comment: thanks for advice, would this command download the extension ? what about permissions and etc .. currently I am just using a docker, CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis